# Android NullPointerException: ImageButton not found in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Can you help me solve this NullPointer problem? I have one list in a fragment and in each row  I have a text view and an image button. I want to show a toast when the user clicks the image button.

Unfortunately, I am getting an error because **imgBtn** is null.

Stack trace:

```
08-31 15:31:27.156  27434-27434/com.example.naveen.tabsfavourite E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.naveen.tabsfavourite, PID: 27434
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.naveen.tabsfavourite.Fragmentone.onCreateView(Fragmentone.java:46)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1942)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1132)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code

**fragment.java**

```
public class Fragmentone  extends Fragment{

    ArrayList<String> name;
    boolean isPressed=false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        name=new ArrayList<String>();
        name.add("First Station");
        name.add("Second Station");


        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        //This is where I try to find the button in the layout file
        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);

        //This is where I get the NullPointerException: imgBtn is null  
        imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image is click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.row_layout,R.id.station_name,name);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        return view;
    }

}
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#325633"
   >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_view">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**row_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/station_name"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#eee345"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/start"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
     />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you have to add the ImageButton in the same xml that contains the ListView, or get rid of it

Comment: This `ImageButton android:id="@+id/favorite"` is **not found** in the inflated layout (`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);`)

Comment: how to remove that bug

Comment: You should find a `tutorial` on how to populate a ListView. There's possibly also explained how to manage its item clicks.

Comment: problem is not click event problem is that using fragment

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `favorite` is in the fragment layout here:

```
    ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
```

but it's not: it's on each of the rows. If you need to access it, you first need to actually put something in the list view, then go through the children and apply the button click listener to each one of them.

Comment: how I will achieve this

Answer (score 0):

this is how i use to access the clicked rows.
you need to change your view, now it's not the fragment but it's row_layout like this:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,null, false);
```

and then you continue with your image button:

```
ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
```

you assume that, you are inflating fragment_one layout, and

here,

```
ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
```

your code claims that favorite ImageButton is in the fragment_one layout. But it's not.

First, whether, you need to inflate row_layout instead of fragmentone :
(Change)

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
```

to -->

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, container, false);
```

OR

include row_layout inside of fragment_one layout. like :

**fragment_one.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#325633"
   >

 <include layout="@layout/row_layout"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_view">
    </ListView>

   </LinearLayout>
```